# Copy black pixels from image and paste in same image with offset

Tags: python, image-processing

[image]I've been trying to get some masking to work in my pictures, but I guess there has to be an easier way to do this:

a) I have an BW picture (photo) showing numbers from a display, "test.png" ( 1000x300 px)

b) I want to copy (only) the black pixels and paste them in the same image

c) When pasting, I want the paste to be offset by its "original" place by 20px (both x/y)

I try running the code below but get an error:

```
import cv2
test = Image.open('test.png')
np = Image.new('1', (1000, 300), 255)
mask = np.bitwise_and(test, np.roll(test, 20, (0,1)))
mask.save('mask.png')
```

I get AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'bitwise_and'

Comment: A picture is worth a 1,000 words...

Comment: Image added. This image will be processed and filtered for noiseremoval etc. before use.

Answer (score 0):

If image is logical (0/1) then:

```
res=np.bitwise_and(image, np.roll(image, 20, (0,1)))
```

Comment: Added code with your suggestion. It would indeed remove alot of my previous code if I get it to work :)

Comment: add:
import numpy as np

Comment: and convert image to bitonal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load image and make Numpy array
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('L')
na = np.array(im)

# Get x,y coordinates of black pixels
Y, X = np.where(na==0)

# Make pixels 30 across and 30 down from them black
na[Y+30, X+30] = 0

# Convert back to PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(na).save('result.png')
```

[image]